# How do i convert this curl commant to c#?

Tags: c#, curl

I am struggeling to convert a curl command to functioning c# code.

```
curl "https://MY_SERVER/api/3.4/sites/site-id/workbooks" -X POST -H "X-Tableau-Auth:credentials token" -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" -F "request_payload=@publish-workbook.xml" -F "tableau_workbook=@MY_WORKBOOK.twbx"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [curl to C# converter](https://curl.olsh.me/)

Answer (score 0):

Using [curl to C# convertor](https://curl.olsh.me/) I've got this result:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://my_server/api/3.4/sites/site-id/workbooks"))
   {
      request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Tableau-Auth", "credentials token");

      var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
      multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("publish-workbook.xml")), 
      "request_payload", Path.GetFileName("publish-workbook.xml"));
   
      multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("MY_WORKBOOK.twbx")), 
      "tableau_workbook", Path.GetFileName("MY_WORKBOOK.twbx"));
   
      request.Content = multipartContent;

      var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
   }
}
```

In "Path.GetFileName()" you should change the file path.

Comment: Hey thanks for our solution but it doesnt work since the MultipartFormDataContent() function uses content type multipart/form-data and not multipart/mixed.

Answer (score 0):

use some online converter or make custom one. its on you.

C# of your curl below:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
 using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://my_server/api/3.4/sites/site-id/workbooks"))
{
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Tableau-Auth", "credentials token"); 
    var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("publish-workbook.xml")), "request_payload", Path.GetFileName("publish-workbook.xml"));
    multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("MY_WORKBOOK.twbx")), "tableau_workbook", Path.GetFileName("MY_WORKBOOK.twbx"));
    request.Content = multipartContent; 
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesnt work i tried this solution using this converter https://curl.olsh.me/.
The problem is, that here the content type is "multipart/form-data" and not "multipart/mixed". Atleast this is the error the api throws.